# Validate town and postal code string against a certain format using JavaScript's RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, postal-code, city

I get an input for a town name and postal code.

I want to check if this input is in the correct format (specified below).
Checking if the town exists is not needed.

---

I wanted to use a RegEx (Regular Expression) to check it, but I couldn't find a correct solution.

---

**Valid Input Formats:**

```
<Town Name> <Post Code>
<Town Name>, <Post Code>
```

**Example Inputs:**

```
Hamburg, 22850
Cambridge 44922
```

I want to check if the letters and the numbers are separated by a space (with an optional comma straight after the town name).

Comment: If you are simply looking for the postal code, then this should be all you need: `(\d{5})$`

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs exactly but i want to check the town name in combination with a comma and the postal code. every part itself isn't a problem ;)

Comment: I was basing that response off your statement, _"Checking if the town exists is not needed."_ But you can use `([\w\s]+),?\s(\d{5})$`, which contains 2 capturing groups. `$1` will return the town, `$2` will return the postal code. [See it Live Here](https://regex101.com/r/2xzEtn/1)

Answer (score 0):

This is the RegEx that you are looking for:

```
^[A-Za-z]+,? [0-9]{5}$
```

[Try it online!](http://www.regexr.com/3ui3i)

---

**Explanation**

```
 [A-Za-z]+               Checks that the first bit is just letters from A to Z (case-insensitive).
          ,?             Allows for 0 or 1 comma(s)
            ␠           Checks whether there is a space
              [0-9]{5}   Checks whether the second half is only made up of 5 digits from 0 to 9
^                     $  Makes sure that the Town Name and Post Code is all that the string contains
```

Comment: Is there a way to check that a postal code has a length of exact 5?

Comment: There is, give me just a second to update the answer